# Linq to XML Namespace problems

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Greetings,

**My goal:** To validate an XML document then load the data into a custom object.  I'm using Linq to XML.

**My situation:** I'm struggling with the Namespace and/or the Linq syntax.  I thought everything was working.  The code reads the XML and loads the object, but realized the XDocument.Validate was passing everything through and not really validating.  I guess that's lax validation.  To get the XDocument.Validate() method to validate, I added a Namespace to the XML file.  The Validation works, but now the XElement created by my Linq Query returns null when trying to access .Element("Field").value.

**My questions:**

1. How can I both validate the XML document and access the value of the Elements?  Should I use another process to validate the XML against an XSD besides using XDocument.Validate?
2. Is the problem in my Linq query?
3. When I try to specify a specific Element in the Linq query, I never get results.  It
   only works when it is

   ```
   IEnumerable<XElement> residents =
           from xeRes in xD.Elements()
           select xeRes;
   ```

   but

   ```
   IEnumerable<XElement> residents =
           from xeRes in xD.Elements("Resident")
           select xeRes;
   ```

returns nothing.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Thank you,

Code Snipets:

XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  <xsd:schema xmlns="http://kinduit.net/ResidentNS" xmlns:schema="http://kinduit.net/ResidentNS" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sqltypes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" elementFormDefault="qualified"><xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes/sqltypes.xsd" />
<xsd:element name="Resident">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="FacilityID">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:varchar" sqltypes:localeId="1033" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth" sqltypes:sqlSortId="52">
                        <xsd:maxLength value="50" />
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="ResidentID"  maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:varchar" sqltypes:localeId="1033" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth" sqltypes:sqlSortId="52">
                        <xsd:maxLength value="20" />
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="ResidentID2"  maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:varchar" sqltypes:localeId="1033" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth" sqltypes:sqlSortId="52">
                        <xsd:maxLength value="20" />
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>...
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><Resident xmlns="http://kinduit.net/ResidentNS">
<FacilityID>WARMSPRINGS</FacilityID>
<ResidentID>WS585459</ResidentID>
<ResidentID2>145214</ResidentID2>...
```

C#

```
        // Validate XML Schema...
        XmlSchemaSet sc = new XmlSchemaSet();
        XNamespace xNs = "http://kinduit.net/ResidentNS";

        try
        {
            // Validate against the XSD...
            string location = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ElementsBC.Interface)).Location;
            sc.Add(xNs.ToString(), location.Replace("ElementsBC.dll", "") + "\\InterfaceXSD\\resident.xsd");
            XDocument xD = this.ConvertToXDocument(ResidentXML);
            xD.Validate(sc, (sender, e) => { throw new Exception(e.Message); }, true);

            IEnumerable<XElement> residents =
                from xeRes in xD.Elements()
                select xeRes;

            counts[0] = residents.Count();

            foreach (XElement el in residents)
            {
                try
                {
                    // get facility...
                    string facilityid = el.Element("FacilityID").Value.ToString();
```

This last line returns null if there is a Namespace in the XML.  If there is no Namespace, this code runs lax Validation, but can read the value.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to include the namespace in the call.

```
XNamespace ns = xD.GetDefaultNamespace() // Or some other way of getting the namespace you want.
IEnumerable<XElement> residents = from xeRes in xD.Elements(ns + "Resident")        
                                  select xeRes;
```

Comment: Tim, along with needing to include the namespace in the call like you said, I was also missing the targetedNamespace in my XSD.  I also had to add the namespace when calling the .Element.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Tim Jarvis and Broken Glass.  I found the answer by combining their responses.  I had three problems with the above code.

1. I was missing the **targetNamespace** in the XSD.
2. I needed to **add the Namespace in my Linq query** as indicated by Tim Jarvis and Broken Glass.
3. I needed to **add the Namespace in the XName parameter on XElement.Element**.

See corrected code below.

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xsd:schema xmlns:xs="http://kinduit.net/ResidentNS" targetNamespace="http://kinduit.net/ResidentNS" xmlns="http://kinduit.net/ResidentNS" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sqltypes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes/sqltypes.xsd" />
<xsd:element name="Resident">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="FacilityID">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:varchar" sqltypes:localeId="1033" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth" sqltypes:sqlSortId="52">
                        <xsd:maxLength value="50" />
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="ResidentID"  maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:varchar" sqltypes:localeId="1033" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth" sqltypes:sqlSortId="52">
                        <xsd:maxLength value="20" />
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="ResidentID2"  maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:varchar" sqltypes:localeId="1033" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth" sqltypes:sqlSortId="52">
                        <xsd:maxLength value="20" />
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>...
```

**XML**: no changes

**C#**

```
 // Validate XML Schema...
        XmlSchemaSet sc = new XmlSchemaSet();
        XNamespace xNs = "http://kinduit.net/ResidentNS";

        try
        {
            // Validate against the XSD...
            string location = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ElementsBC.Interface)).Location;
            sc.Add(xNs.ToString(), location.Replace("ElementsBC.dll", "") + "\\InterfaceXSD\\resident.xsd");
            XDocument xD = this.ConvertToXDocument(ResidentXML);
            xD.Validate(sc, (sender, e) => { throw new Exception(e.Message); }, true);

            IEnumerable<XElement> residents = 
                from xeRes in xD.Elements(xNs + "Resident")
                select xeRes;

            counts[0] = residents.Count();

            foreach (XElement el in residents)
            {
                try
                {
                    // get facility...
                    string facilityid = el.Element(xNs + "FacilityID").Value.ToString();
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare and use a namespace:

```
XNamespace xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
```

Also there are no `Resident` elements in your XML - there are elements named `element` that have an attribute `name` that starts with "Resident" though. These elements are not direct children of the root node so you have to use `Descendands()` instead of `Elements()` in your query.

Having said that this works for me (returns 3 nodes):

```
XDocument xD = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
XNamespace xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";

IEnumerable<XElement> residents = from xeRes in xD.Descendants(xsd + "element")
                                  where xeRes.Attribute("name") != null 
                                  && xeRes.Attribute("name").Value.StartsWith("Resident") 
                                  select xeRes;
```

Comment: Should "element" and "name" be replaced with values from my XML file?  How would the Linq look if using my XSD/XML?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: "element" and "name" *are taken* from your XML file given in your sample, see `<xsd:element/>` in your XML